# Testing ActiveRecord:Observer using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, observer-pattern

I have a model class as follows:

```
class DataInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {:UNAPPROVED => 1, :APPROVED => 2, :PROCESSED => 3 }
  attr_accessible :id, :owner, :status
  validates :status, :inclusion => {:in => STATUS.values}    
end
```

I have written a observer as follows:

```
class StatusObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(datainfo)
    if datainfo.status.eql? "APPROVED"
      DataInfoWorker.perform_async datainfo.id
    end 
  end
end
```

How do I test the observer using RSpec? Do I necessarily have to use "No Peeping Toms" plugin? I mainly want test after_save part of it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this using rspec-3 syntax:

```
describe DataInfo do
  describe 'after save when status is APPROVED' do
    let(:data_info) { DataInfo.new(status: :APPROVED) }

    before do
      data_info.save!
    end

    it 'queues DataInfoWorker' do
      expect(DataInfoWorker.jobs.size).to eq 1
    end

  end
end
```

Updated to test that a Sidekiq job is queued.  Make sure that the `rspec-sidekiq` gem is added to your `Gemfile`.